# How to design an SKNode in a graphical designer and reuse it in code?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

Because of the fact that SpriteKit does not support custom drawing on `SKNode`s, I have to create a custom sprite node and add other nodes to it.

When I am adding other nodes to the parent node, the coordinate system of the parent view is really confusing me. I always have to try a lot of times to get the node to the place where I want it to be. Sometimes I can't even see the node added.

I think this is very annoying. I think SpriteKit must provide some way to let me "design" a custom node in a graphical way. I want something like the SKScene designer. But instead of designing a scene, I can design a node. After that, I can reuse the designed node in code, just like I can reuse table view cells that are already designed in IB.

Is there something like that in Xcode?

Comment: There is no problem, at least nothin related to customizing nodes, I think you must insist on learning coordinate systems, they are really easy to use. Give us an example of what cause you trouble.

Comment: Not completly sure of what your probleme is (coordinates or drawing), but there is no way to design your node directly in xcode just like a SKScene. But you can create your custom drawing using photoshop/gimp/whatever and display the created image in your scene using a SKSpriteNode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The coordinate system is really easy to understand, when you place a node inside another node, the coordinates become relative to parent, not the scene.

Since SKScenes are SKNodes, you can use the sks file to design your nodes on a per node basis and load an sks for every node you need, or you can create several nodes inside 1 SKScene file, and just extract them from the sks during your loading phase.

Comment: Do you mean I need to create an sks file, design my node in it, and call the SKNode(fileNamed:) constructor? Then add the node returned to the Scene?

Comment: I am not familiar with the iOS9 implementation of loading sks files,  I am still using the unarchive method, so you would need to test that part out, but yes